# La « crosse amovible de mitraillage/tir par rafales » : emploi et autres propositions ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, terminologie

Je [lisais](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201902/13/01-5214599-un-an-apres-la-tuerie-de-parkland-lamerique-bouge-lentement-sur-les-armes.php) qu'un an après la tuerie de la Saint-Valentin à Parkland en Floride (États-Unis) on avait réussi à faire étendre « en décembre l'interdiction des *bump stocks* à l'ensemble des États-Unis » entamant un recul lent mais certain des pires aberrations en ce qui a trait aux outils de [meurtre de masse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuerie_de_masse).

Au GDT on a [proposé](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26544014) en 2017 les termes « crosse amovible de mitraillage » et « crosse amovible de tir par rafales » pour ce dispositif.

---

- A-t-on retenu l'un ou l'autre de ces termes et/ou autrement y a-t-il d'autres termes dans la francophonie qui servent à désigner cette abomination  ?

Answer (score 0):

Il me semble que *crosse à glissière de tir automatique* serait concluant, et moins lourd que ce qui est proposé. Voir [ici](https://www.armes-ufa.com/spip.php?article2264) pour le bien-fondé du terme *glissière*.

> Les "Bump Stocks" sont des crosses à glissière, qui récupèrent l’énergie engendrée par le recul de l’arme pour actionner la détente. Lorsqu’il est monté sur une arme semi-automatique, ce genre de dispositif permet de tirer à une cadence accélérée analogue à celle d’un tir par rafales (400 à 800 coups par minute).

Comment: C'est la seule citation de *glissière* de cette source.

Answer (score 0):

Je vais y aller de mes propositions car je trouve les équivalents français pas  totalement satisfaisants.

D'abord, en alternative à "crosse à glissière", si on insiste sur les caractéristiques de l'objet :

- crosse coulissante
- crosse à ressort

Si on insiste sur le comportement obtenu, ce qui colle plus à l'expression originale, on pourrait proposer :

- crosse à rebond
- crosse va-et-vient
- crosse aller-retour

Answer (score 0):

S'agissant d'un terme technique, n'importe lequel pourra être retenu à partir du moment où les vendeurs ou fabricants le choisissent.

Pour en emploi dans la langue courante, « crosse amovible de tir par rafales » me semble plus naturel. Mais attention, la langue courante emploi par exemple le mot gâchette pour désigner la détente d'un fusil ou d'un pistolet (alors que la gâchette est la pièce interne à l'arme qui libère le percuteur) ...